# Proving prime counting function formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, proof-writing, prime-numbers

So on this [page](https://oeis.org/w/index.php?title=Formulas_for_primes&oldid=1610559#cite_note-17) there is a formula that was made by a 14-year-old by the name of Minac for the prime counting function. It is as follows: $$\pi(n)=\sum_{k=2}^n\left\lfloor\frac{(k-1)!+1}k-\left\lfloor\frac{(k-1)!}k\right\rfloor\right\rfloor$$How do we prove this? I do know that $$\pi(n)=\sum_{k=2}^n1_{k\in\mathbb{P}}$$So $$1_{k\in\mathbb{P}}=\left\lfloor\frac{(k-1)!+1}k-\left\lfloor\frac{(k-1)!}k\right\rfloor\right\rfloor$$(Where $1_{k\in\mathbb{P}}$ is $1$ when $k$ is prime, $0$ otherwise)What now?

I have a feeling that this has to do with Wilson's theorem. The expression in the floor function (that is in the floor function) is the same as the expression outside the second floor function but is less by $\frac1k$.

Comment: It is also anyone's guess why the second expression is inside the first. If $n$ is already an integer, then $\lfloor a-n\rfloor=\lfloor a\rfloor -n$. Thus, they could've expressed the formula as $$\pi(n)=\sum_{k=2}^n\left(\left\lfloor\frac{(k-1)!+1}k\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{(k-1)!}k\right\rfloor\right)$$

Comment: Now you only need to prove that the expression in the bracket is $1$ if $k$ is prime, $0$ otherwise. (You are right, Wilson's theorem plays the role here!) In fact, $\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{a-1}{b}\rfloor=\begin{cases}1&b\mid a\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop The answer is now a giveaway. I will accept it if you make it an answer :)